# How to get data based on Block-Height?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

in EVM we can call any read-only function and pass it a block_height we would want the data to be returned on.

for example if I wanted a pool's liquidity at block height 999999, i would call that liquidity function and pass it the blockheight .

`contract.liquidity({ blockTag: 999999 })`

is there something equivalent on cardano?